# Toggling button text using ternary operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-operator

I am trying to toggle button text by using ternary operator but it is not working.

```
<button type="button" id="ter" >Bar</button>

$("#ter").click(function(){
   $(this).text() = 'Bar' ? 'column':'Bar';
});
```

Is this possible to do this way? and what part I am doing wrong? I know there many other ways to achieve this but I just need to know if it is possible in this method or not?

Answer (score 6):

You could also try this:

```
$("#ter").click(function(){
    var newText = ($(this).text() == 'Bar') ? 'column':'Bar';
    $(this).text(newText);
});
```

This checks if the current text is equal to 'Bar' with `$(this).text() == 'Bar'`.  If it is, it sets the variable newText to 'column' (or vice versa).  The second line replaces the old text with the new text.

Comment: Is this a valid statement - $(this).text((($(this).text() == 'Bar') ? 'column':'Bar'));

Comment: can I add a console.log() to options as follows?

$("#ter").click(function(){
    var newText = ($(this).text() == 'Bar') ? 
('column', console.log('column')) :
('Bar', console.log('Bar') ;
 $(this).text(newText);
});


I checked this but it didn't work, how can I add the console.log() ?

Answer (score 6):

You are using the ternary operator wrong. It goes:

```
[statement] ? [code when true] : [code when false]
```

You're basically testing `if('Bar')` right now which will always return true.

Comment: I was about to add that to my own answer (incremental edits are *slow* on tablets); but I saw you had it covered. So: plus-one!

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it wrong, you could instead use this approach:

```
$("#ter").click(function(){
   $(this).text(function (i, t) {
       return t === 'Bar' ? 'column':'Bar';
   });
});
```

The reason it didn't work is because:

1. You were trying to *assign* a result to `$(this).text()` (using `=`) instead of *comparing* (`==` or `===`), and
2. Not returning anything to update the text

It's important to note that with jQuery the `text()` method (and most others) when called with no arguments is a *getter* (it gets the current value), but to use it as a *setter* you have to pass an argument, either directly (`$(this).text('foo')`) or using the anonymous function (`$(this).text(function(){ return 'foo'; })`). Calling the getter, and comparing that retrieved value (or trying to assign to it) does not act as a setter.

In the anonymous functions available to jQuery methods, the first argument (here called `i`, but the name is irrelevant, it's always the first argument) is the index of the current '`$(this)`' object in the collection returned by jQuery, the second argument (here called `t`, but again the name is irrelevant) represents the current (pre-manipulation) value found by the method.

References:

- [`text()`](http://api.jQuery.com/text/).

Comment: Thanks David just can you please also let me know what is the i parameter for? I kinda understand the t there but what is i?